# Ruby on Rails calculation results + Prawn PDF Generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I'm using `Prawn` to generator PDFs.  I've created a basic `index` view that does some simple calculations and displays the answers when submit button is pressed.

Problem is, I can't figure out how to take these answers and have them exported to Prawn.  When I send it to Prawn, it resets the values inputted into the calculator to zero, so it shows the same value no matter what and not the calculated answer displayed.  MVC below.  Really appreciate any help.

Model

```
class Calculator < ApplicationRecord

    def self.to_celsius(fahrenheit)
        (fahrenheit.to_i - 30) / 2
    end

    def self.square_foot(a,b)
        a.to_i * b.to_i
    end
end
```

Controller

```
class CalculatorsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @result = Calculator.to_celsius(params[:fahrenheit])
        @square = Calculator.square_foot(params[:length], params[:width])
    end

    def index
        @result = Calculator.to_celsius(params[:fahrenheit])
        @square = Calculator.square_foot(params[:length], params[:width])
    end


end
```

Views/index.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 calculations">
        <%= form_for :calculators, url: { action: :new },method: :get do |f|   %>

          <p> Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit: </p>
          <%= label_tag :fahrenheit, "Enter Fahrenheit", class: "input-a" %>
          <%= text_field_tag :fahrenheit, params[:fahrenheit] %>

          <p> Square Footage Calculator: </p>         
          <%= label_tag :length, "Enter length ft", class: "input-a" %>
          <%= text_field_tag :length, params[:length] %>

          <%= label_tag :width, "Enter width ft", class: "input-a" %>
          <%= text_field_tag :width, params[:width] %>

          <%= f.submit 'Calculate!' %>
        <% end %>

        <% unless @result.nil? %>
          This is <p> = <%= @result %> degrees celsius! </p>
        <% end %>
        <p><%= link_to "Create PDF", calculators_path(:format => 'pdf') %></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and which method  `calculators_path` use?

Comment: @inye It connects to `index.pdf.prawn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My controller was the problem.  Needed to add a line to `render :index`

So new controller is:

```
class CalculatorsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @result = Calculator.to_celsius(params[:fahrenheit])
        @square = Calculator.square_foot(params[:length], params[:width])
        render :index
    end

    def index
    end    


end
```

Comment: this is the solution?